# What are the chart/map options, without using XML?

Tags: graph, maps

I'm looking for a chart/map library that can do a wide variety of graphs and maps, including treemaps, worldmap, line/pie charts etc.  The data is going to come from the database, so I am not looking at XML/CSV stuff.  It should also have at least minimal interactive options, like zooming etc.

fusioncharts looks good, anybody has other (cheaper) suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: A big help for anyone looking to answer this would be information regarding what platform and infrastructure you're targeting. Are you developing for the desktop, or the web? Windows, linux, ASP.NET, php? Or something else entirely?

Answer (score 0):

I am very fond of [Dundas charts and maps](http://www.dundas.com/), but they aren't free.

Here is a list of [Open Source Charting & Reporting Tools in C#](http://csharp-source.net/open-source/charting-and-reporting)
and [another list for ASP.Net](http://www.asp.net/community/control-gallery/browse.aspx?category=7).

[ASP.Net has a Charting Control](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/11/24/new-asp-net-charting-control-lt-asp-chart-runat-quot-server-quot-gt.aspx)

Here is a tutorial [A Look at WebCharts, a Free .NET Charting Control](https://web.archive.org/web/20210802163635/https://aspnet.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/120804-1.aspx)

**You can find lots of other SO recommendations by searching using tags for [charts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/charts), [maps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/maps) and [graphs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/graph).**

**For example, for PHP, this was a very popular question: [Graphs/Charts in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/395541/graphs-charts-in-php)**